# zoomToExtent move to an incorrect position

Tags: openlayers, bounds

I have a process that load a WMS layer in a map with OpenLayers and then using zoomToExtent function should move to a specific position.

```
var bounds = new OpenLayers.Bounds(
   1707244.375, 5086943.5,
   1786059.25, 5171869
);
map.zoomToExtent(bounds);
```

I taked the values directly from the layer XML (from nativeBoundingBox), but when I call zoomToExtent the map mvoe to an incorrect position.
Can you tell me why?
Thank you
bye
stefano

Comment: check projection of the wms layer, must be equal to the same as the bounds

Comment: @phipex how can I get the projection of the wms layer?

Comment: Depends on the map server to which this consulting (Geoserver, Mapserver, etc..), Look at the source where you got the WMS address, you can also look at the petition does OpenLayers using firebug, WebTools, etc.

The information you're giving is to give you a little help, you must at least show the code of the WMS layer

Comment: here is the code:

      var newWms = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS(
          layerName,
          "/geoserver/" + workspaceName + "/wms",
          {
              layers: workspaceName + ":" + layerName
              , transparent: "true"
              , format: "image/png"
              , 'tpiType': 'base'
              , 'tpiLayerId': tpiLayerId
              , 'tpiLayerRecord': selectedRow
          },
          {
            isBaseLayer: false
            , singleTile: true
          }
      );
      
      map.addLayer(newWms);

Comment: The code is not saying much, you have to verify the projection map server and compare it with the projection map http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.getProjection

Comment: what do you mean with projection map server? how can I get it?

Comment: There are many map servers, did not say in which these consulting, you can be guided by the petition does openlayers, I recommend you decumentes more about the WMS protocol, I think you have a problem of concept so I recommend that you search more documentation
http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Category:Free_GIS_Book